# Reordering Realm objects in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, realm

I have a collection of `RLMObject` model objects representing login accounts that a user
can manage in my app. These objects are exposed by being mapped directly to a `UITableView`
in the apps.

Since the user can explicitly control the ordering of these account objects via
the table view, the model object features a property called `orderedIndex` in order
to track the current ordering of the objects.

```
@interface Account : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSInteger orderedIndex;

@end
```

The table view data source accesses these accounts from an `RLMResults` property
member of the parent view controller

```
self.accounts = [[Account allObjects] sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"orderedIndex" ascending:YES];
```

(Thanks to the fact that Realm objects are 'live', I never have to manually reload
or reset this object.)

When the user re-orders the rows of the table view, the `orderedIndex` property of all
of these Realm objects needs to be updated to match.

There's probably many different ways of doing this, some more complex than others,
but what would be the easiest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I tried to be smart about this in determining which specific Realm objects
were affected by the move, and only modifying their `orderedIndex` values, but this turned
out to be somewhat complex, and in certain edge cases (Usually involving objects at the top and bottom),
would lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Ultimately, I decided for ultimate simplicity (At the expense of slightly more work), I would
simply copy the contents of my `self.accounts` object to a mutable array, perform the
move operation in the array, and then simply rebuild the `orderedIndex` of each object 
from scratch there.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{   
   if (sourceIndexPath.row == destinationIndexPath.row) {
       return;
   }

   // Make a mutable copy of the accounts list
   NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (Account *account in self.accounts) {
       [array addObject:account];
   }

   // Re-order this array as dictated by the table view
   Account *accountToMove = array[sourceIndexPath.row];
   [array removeObject:accountToMove];
   [array insertObject:accountToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

   // Loop through all of the items and reset their index value
   [self.accounts.realm transactionWithBlock:^{
       NSInteger i = 0;
       for (Account *account in array) {
           account.orderedIndex = i++;
       }
   }];
}
```

That ended up working perfectly. :)

Comment: Just another idea you could consider in the future is using a float or double for your order property. To determine a record's new order, you simply average the orders of the rows it will fall between, meaning you only have to update a single record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to solve this problem is to use the `List` data structure from Realm. So you can have a List of Realm objects and reordering the elements inside the list is exactly the same as how you would reorder for a regular array. If interested, you can check out the following link to see how this is done for Swift. :-)

[Incorrect UI update after reordering rows in UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647582/incorrect-ui-update-after-reordering-rows-in-uitableviewcontroller)

Comment: Do you mind me asking, was your `List` data structure stored in Realm, or in memory? I just implemented a `Sorter` realm object with a `let items = List<Item>()` property to store my `Item`s in and keep their ordering, which works, but I'm wondering if I needed to do all that work, or if there's a better way.